# Logging Response bodies in action filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, action-filter, actionfilterattribute, asp.net-mvc-filters

I have the following code in a class that implements `IAsyncActionFilter` using .Net Core.

```
public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    await next.Invoke();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Response.Body))
    {
        var responseBodyText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        var messageObjToLog = new
        {
            responseBody = responseBodyText,
            statusCode = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode
        };
        _logger.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageObjToLog));
        context.HttpContext.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }
}
```

This line:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Response.Body))
```

produces the following error

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>
> Connection id "0HLFBE2K7NSD3", Request id "0HLFBE2K7NSD3:00000001": An
>   unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable.    at
>   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean
>   detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
>   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream)    at
>   Adapter.Logging.Middleware.LogResponseFilter.d__2.MoveNext()
>   in C:\src\Adapter\Logging\Middleware\LogRequestResponseFilter.cs:line
>   56
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__10.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__22.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
>   Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__17.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__15.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext()

My question is:

What do I need to do in order to safely reset the response stream?

I have another implementation of IAsyncActionFilter for logging:

```
public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            var requestBodyText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            context.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();
            context.HttpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var messageObjToLog = new
            {
                scheme = context.HttpContext.Request.Scheme,
                host = context.HttpContext.Request.Host,
                path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path,
                queryString = context.HttpContext.Request.Query,
                requestBody = requestBodyText
            };
            _logger.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageObjToLog));
        }

        await next.Invoke();
    }
```

Comment: You should make your post more detailed and reformat the error message.

Comment: Maybe try [Result filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#result-filters) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Probably put "await next.Invoke();" at the end of the method.